# NodeJS is running one script into another one

Tags: node.js, api, server, require, module.exports

I created a TCP server for receiving information from some devices, and I wanted to created an API out from this server, and I exported two variables in order to use them in the API.
When I do that, my server starts in my other process, making that they execute at the same time, I don't know why this happens

```
//server.js

const { title, BL_url, puerto_controladores, puerto_api } = require('...')
process.title = title;

var net = require('net');

var sockets = []; 
var socketsID = [];
var lastConnected = [];


var server = net.createServer( function (socket) {

    socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort;

    sockets.push(socket);
    socketsID.push(socket.name.substr(7));

    console.log(socket.name + ' connected.');

    socket.on('data', (data) => {
        textChunk = data.toString('utf8').substr(1,data.toString('utf8').length-2);
        console.log('Mensaje de ' + socket.name.substr(7) + 
    socket.on('close', () =>{
        console.log(socket.name + " desconectado.");
    });
    socket.on('error', (error) =>{
        console.log('Error del Cliente TCP: ' + puerto_controladores, error.code, error.message);
    });
    
});

server.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('Error del Server TCP: ' + puerto_controladores, error.message);
});

server.listen(puerto_controladores, ()=>{
    setInterval(() => {
        webMethods.sendInterval();
    }, 180000);

    
    console.log("Server listening at : " + puerto_controladores);
});
//setInterval(()=>{
    module.exports = {sockets,socketsID};
```

On the other hand:

```
const {sockets,socketsID} = require('..server.js');
const {titleProcess,port} = require('...');
process.title = titleProcess;
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Listening at :',port);
});

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(test.sockets,test.socketsID);
    res.status(200).json({
        mensaje: 'received',

    })
})
```

Whatever I do in the server.js, a print of module.export, a new variable, including the title of process in command prompt etc. it runs in the API.js console

```
//API Output: 
Server listening at : 9006
Listening at : 4002
{ sockets: [], socketsID: [] }
{ sockets: [], socketsID: [] }

//Server Output:
Error del Server TCP: 9006 listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::9006
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here, but each of your two files each starts their own server.  That's what they are written to do.  When you `require("../server.js)`, that runs that module which attempts to start up a new server.  Is that not what you are expecting?

Comment: No, I just want to use server.js as server and api.js as an API, not creating a new server when I run api.js, I just want to use sockets and socketsID from server.js in my API side without start a new server when I ``require('../server.js')``.

Comment: Well, that's not you this type of code works.  If you're trying to get data from server.js in another process, you will have to use some sort of interprocess communication to do that and you cannot directly share Javascript variables like an array of sockets.  Modules don't do that for you.  Modules all run in the SAME process.  Running a module in another process creates a whole new instance of that module with its own data, own servers, etc...

Comment: This whole thing would be a whole lot easier if your two servers were in the same process and thus the same nodejs app.  If you can't do that, then you'll have to back up multiple steps and describe what you're really trying to share between two server processes and why because you need a completely different approach to solving whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I know, it'd be easier if I could make a unique server-api but the requirements are they have to be separated, do you have any idea about those interprocess communication?

Comment: Please read my last comment.  I can't help you further without additional information.

Comment: I want to be able to send TCP frames through socket object. In the front-end I write the device and that is gonna choose the right socket to stablish the communications, this process is through API and some post and gets from front end, which knows sockets (for all connected sockets in the server) and socketsID (compares the device and its address with the sockets addresses)

Comment: Well `socket` objects in nodejs belong to a particular process.  You can't just share them with another process.  If you want one process to cause data to be sent on a socket the other process owns, then send the data itself to the other process using a different server and send some identifier with the data that the receiving process can use to figure out which socket the data should be sent to and it will then send the data over the socket it has.  But, this whole thing sounds like a really confusing way to do things.

Comment: For example, let's say you have serverTCP (the plain TCP server from your server.js) and serverAPI (an Express server from your other file).  Put a separate Express server in serverTCP running on a local port, not open to the outside world.  When serverAPI receives some data for some socketID, it then makes an http request to serverTCP and sends the data and the socketID.  serverTCP receives that http request, gets the socketID and the data out of that request and sends it out over the appropriate socket it has a connection to.

Comment: That is very useful, it could work. I'll try to do that. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `socket` objects in nodejs belong to a particular process. You can't just share them with another process easily. If you want one process to cause data to be sent on a socket the other process owns, then send the data itself to the other process using a different server and send some identifier with the data that the receiving process can use to figure out which socket the data should be sent to and it will then send the data over the socket it has. But, this whole thing sounds like a really confusing way to do things.

For example, let's say you have serverTCP (the plain TCP server from your server.js) and serverAPI (an Express server from your other file) each in separate processes. Put a separate Express server in serverTCP running on a local port, not open to the outside world. When serverAPI receives some data for some socketID, it then makes an http request to serverTCP and sends the data and the socketID. serverTCP receives that http request, gets the socketID and the data out of that request and sends it out over the appropriate socket it has a connection to.

FYI, this is generically known as a proxy where your API is somewhat serving as a proxy for the real socket connection.  There are all sorts of modules in NPM that implement actual proxies too.